# Стоит ли использовать 'password_hash()' для защиты паролей в БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как я вижу, есть два варианта, более-менее защитить пользовательские пароли, расположенные в БД MySQL, в случае незаконного проникновения.

**1.Вариант:**
связываем пользовательский **пароль**+**соль**, полученные данные проганяем через метод шифрования **XOR** по ключевому слову, и это все обращаем в хеш-код методом **SHA256**.

Шифр для **XOR**, храним в закрытой для доступа папке, на один уровень выше корневого элемента сайта. 
**Соль** и **SHA256** -  в БД.

**2.Вариант:**
Использовать стандартную функцию **password_hash()**  и **password_verify()** , и больше ничего не делать.

Подскажите, стоит ли использовать **password_hash**, или лучше все таки реализовать **первый вариант**?

Comment: Первый вариант не спасет от получения ключа для XOR, если атакующий кроме слития базы сможет и добавлять новых пользователей и знает алгоритм работы. Причем ему нужно будет добавить всего одного пользователя на один байт ключа.

Comment: Так, стоп, новых пользователе допустим создавать нельзя. А что значит - Причем ему нужно будет добавить всего одного пользователя на один байт ключа. Покажете на примере кодом или на пальцах хотя бы))?

Comment: Создается пользователь с паролем "1", из базы известно значение Hash(("1" ^ key[0]) + Salt). Где неизвестно только key[0], для нахождения которого достаточно проверить всего 256 вариантов. Аналогично для всех остальных байтов ключа.

Comment: Ого, и это действительно работает? (

Comment: конечно же нет. Попробовать самому и узнать что-то новое вам что-то мешает?

Comment: И я о нем говорю. Пример атаки и "формулу" привел.

Comment: Спасибо, если действительно работает, очень познавательно. Просто чего то я об этом нигде ничего не видел. Хотя прочитал не мало информации, как по мне.

Comment: А толку от информации, если вы не будете пробовать ломать свои и чужие поделия? Ноль толку.

Comment: Почему же, я практикуюсь

Comment: а sha512 тоже так взламывается?

Comment: Читайте внимательно: "вариант не спасет от получения ключа для XOR"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно стоит. Там соль хронися прямо в хеше. Но мне советовал умный дядя поверх всё равно генерировать свою соль из текущей даты с временем и отрезков неизменных уник. параметров пользователя. И уже будет вдвойне мощно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот прочтите, довольно таки полезная информация http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php

Comment: "При хэшировании паролей рекомендуется применять алгоритм Blowfish" - довольно странный пассаж, особенно для официальной документации. Потому что Blowfish - не хэш.

Comment: встроенные функции лучше, а как в реальности?

Comment: Blowfish это не хеш, это один из алгоритмов криптографии. Ознакомтесь: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish

Comment: @LevBazdyrev я-то знаком, потому и возникают вопросы к приведенной выше цитате.

Comment: не могу понять какие вопросы??

Comment: Blowfish - Стоит узнать шифр и тогда все будет расшифровано?

Comment: @LevBazdyrev Вопрос простой почему для хэширования рекомендуется алгоритм шифрования, а не хэширования.

Comment: @semiromid знание алгоритма шифрования не дает никаких (почти, в общем случае, при грамотной реализации и т.д.) подсказок к нахождению зашифрованных данных.

Comment: @semiromid по ссылке из википедии Вы можете прочитать про криптостойкость данного алгоритма

Comment: Так нет, подсказки и не нужны, если залетят туда где он уже готовый ключик будет лежать. Тогда им не будет никакого труда заполучить всю информацию.

Comment: LevBazdyrev - Да , спасибо, я прочитал, но этого пока мало, нужно еще как говорят, попробовать на вкус )

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов скорее всего из-за соображений безопасность, всё таки шифр и хэш это две разные вещи.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev только это алгоритм шифрования, а не хэширования. Отличие в том, что хэш создавался чтобы нельзя было восстановить исходные данные. А шифр - как раз чтобы можно было.

Comment: @semiromid вобще я скажу что всё познаётся в сравнении, есть ещё методы шифрования, их тоже стоит пробовать.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов давайте не забывать о том что хеш так-же использует криптографические методы. да их нельзя заполучить, но их можно подобрать. Обратить можно внимание на строку из википедии "Следует отметить, что не доказано существование необратимых хеш-функций, для которых вычисление какого-либо прообраза заданного значения хеш-функции теоретически невозможно. Обычно нахождение обратного значения является лишь вычислительно сложной задачей."

Comment: @LevBazdyrev И ГСЧ тоже использует криптографические методы, почему бы вместо данных о пароле не писать случайные числа, если методы те же?

Comment: Идея с хешем все-таки на мой взгляд была лучше. Да , конечно есть свои минусы, но с криптографией легко восстановить все данные. А на то что бы восстановить  sha512 , с солью, наверное нужно больше времени.

Comment: @semiromid а Вы хотите сказать что хотели  использовать чистый метод криптографии???

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов никто не мешает Вам придумать свой алгоритм шифрования, только вот эти алгоритмы не всегда состоят из цифр...

Comment: Да. То есть получается что в password_hash()  - уже есть алгоритм шифрования Blowfish по умолчанию. В качестве ответа на мой вопрос , в настоящие время актуально использовать - password_hash()?

Comment: @semiromid в общем случае нет. Хэш от 8-байтного пароля (с известной солью) - 2^64 прохода алгоритма хэша. Расшифровать блок данных для AES - минимум 2^128 проходов.

Comment: @LevBazdyrev а из чего еще состоят алгоритмы? DES, который может быть реализован "в проводах" прекрасно описывается теми самыми цифрами. Совет изобретать свой алгоритм - глупость в любом случае.

Comment: @semiromid да он уже встроен в данное API, но по его принципу можно переделать под более мощнее. Вот в принципе Владимир Вам дал чётко понять это.

Comment: Почему глупость? Его же никто не будет знать. Главное придумать что то новое , что еще не проросло в умах других людей.

Comment: @semiromid Владимир прав... это действительно глупость, Вы потратите время и нервы, и в итоге ваш шифр окажется всё равно уязвим, я Вам скажу так, нету идеального шифра, который не реально подобрать. Это зависит только от вычислительных возможностей

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов прошу прощения не в ту степь понесло, почему-то к цифрам я ещё символы ASCII добавил, тобишь соль

Comment: как думаете , нормально так будет?  sha512 + password_hash()+ соль

Comment: @semiromid по моему будет много лишнего кода, Вам проще перезаписать функции password_hash() и password_verify() я думаю что sha512 + соль будет достаточно, но если есть возможность укрепить алгоритм, то лучше сделать, то бишь password_hash() будет не лишней

Comment: LevBazdyrev Перезаписать функции? То есть password_hash()+соль1+ password_hash()+ соль2?

Comment: Что-то типа того, только функцию шифрования будет исполнять только одна строка password_hash(); А в нём будет уже Sha512+Blowfish+соль, хотя соль можно вынести за пределы тела функции.

Comment: LevBazdyrev Вот, не рекомендуют её использовать. ........функция crypt() создает слабый пароль. PHP 5.6 ........ Или самому написать функцию по алгоритму из вики, Blowfish? Или может вместо неё еще что-нибудь прикрутить...Может еще одну соль, которая будет хранится не в БД , а в защищенной папке, которая находится на одном уровне c  папкой public_html.  Тогда как раз будет значимое число , три, будет все засолено как надо)

Comment: ЦИТАТА : Далее «использование алгоритма Blowfish» — брееед. Хеш на то и любим разработчиками, что занимает фиксированное место в базе. Blowfish это симметрический шифр, результат которого мало того что может конфликтовать с кодировкой базы, так ещё и вовсе не поместится в строку.

Comment: а sha512  С password_hash() нормально будет помещаться, что то мне кажется что нет? А хотя вроде должно нормаль быть - 255 characters would be a good choice

Comment: @semiromid Не забывайте о том что кроме типа поля Varchar у вас есть другие типы полей, и не забывайте о том что кроме метода Blowfish есть и другие методы криптографии